# nodejs app exited with code 0 when docker-compose up

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I encounter the error below when running docker-compose up

```
nginx_1       | 2018/07/03 06:54:17 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "admin:1123" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:19
nginx_1       | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "admin:1123" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:19
nginx_1 exited with code 1
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

volumes: 
  mongostorage:  

services:  
  app:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - "3000"
    links:
      - mongo
      - redis

    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/app
      - /var/www/app/node_modules

  adminmongo:
    build: ./adminMongo
    ports:
      - "4455"
    links:
      - mongo    
    command: node app.js

  admin:
    build: ./admin
    ports:
      - "1123"
    links:
      - mongo
      - redis
    command: node admin_app.js

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "1123:1123"
      - "4455:4455"
    links:
      - app:app
      - admin:admin

  mongo:
    image: mongo:2.4
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
    volumes:
      - mongostorage:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

dockerfile for app

```
FROM node:9.8
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/app
WORKDIR /var/www/app
COPY . /var/www/app
RUN npm install -g gulp pm2 notify-send
RUN npm install 
CMD ["pm2-docker", "./bin/www"]
```

dockerfile for admin

```
FROM node:9.8
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/sibkladmin
WORKDIR /var/www/sibkladmin
COPY . /var/www/sibkladmin
RUN npm install -g gulp pm2 bcrypt
RUN npm install
```

dockerfile for nginx

```
FROM nginx:latest

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 1123
EXPOSE 4455

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

nginx.conf

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http{

    upstream app.local{
        least_conn;
        server app:3000 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    upstream app.local:4455{
        least_conn;
        server adminmongo:4455 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    upstream app.local:1123{
        least_conn;
        server admin:1123 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }



    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name app.local;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app.local;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 1123;

        server_name app.local:1123;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app.local:1123;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 4455;

        server_name app.local:4455;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://sibklapp.local:4455;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

Updated:

Error received after docker-compose build

```
npm ERR! path /var/www/admin/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/abbrev
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/var/www/admin/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/abbrev' -> '/var/www/admin/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/.abbrev.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-07-05T10_03_43_640Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'admin' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 254
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

#### NGINX dockerfile

Change:

`COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

to

`COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.d`

Remove `EXPOSE` ports no need to expose ports.

#### Compose File

Update compose file to:

```yaml
version: "2"

volumes: 
  mongostorage:  

services:  
  app:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/app
      - /var/www/app/node_modules
    command: node app.js

  adminmongo:
    build: ./adminMongo
    ports:
      - "4455:4455"
    links:
      - mongo    
    volumes:
      - ./adminMongo:/var/www/adminMongo
      - /var/www/adminMongo/node_modules
    command: node app.js

  admin:
    build: ./admin
    ports:
      - "1123:1123"
    links:
      - mongo
      - redis
    volumes:  
      - ./admin:/var/www/admin
      - /var/www/admin/node_modules
    command: node admin_app.js

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    links:
      - app:app
      - admin:admin

  mongo:
    image: mongo:2.4
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
    volumes:
      - mongostorage:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

**NOTE**
 I created a simple node hello world app to test, you will need to update the `command:` to match what you have in `package.json`

**Also**
Before you start your app run these commands to clean up any old containers/networks:

```
    docker-compose kill
    docker-compose down
    docker network prune
    docker volume prune
```

To start the services Run:

`docker-compose build`

prob overkill but makes sure you're not using old containers

`docker-compose up --force-recreate`

#### Local Test Output

```
    mongo_1       | Wed Jul  4 21:50:35.835 [initandlisten] waiting 
    for connections on port 27017

    mongo_1       | Wed Jul  4 21:50:35.835 [websvr] admin web console 
    waiting for connections on port 28017

    app_1         | app listening on port 3000!
    admin_1       | admin app listening on port 1123!
    adminmongo_1  | AdminMongo app listening on port 4455!

    redis_1       | 1:M 04 Jul 21:50:26.523 * Running mode=standalone, 
    port=6379.
```

Comment: i have updated the question with nginx.conf, thanks.

Comment: Updated answer with nginx fix, basically just appends your config to the default nginx config. Should work

Comment: this error msg returned: admin_1 exited with code 0

Comment: however, app_1 is running well

Comment: Interesting I used the code you shared and everything is working (just a hello node app.

Comment: added compose file, tested locally and worked, used same file structure with a `hello world` node app to test.

Comment: Are you able to edit like a Jade file at admin and auto updated on the server?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. i think this should work. However, i encounter new error in admin app while running docker-compose build. I have clear my node_modules folder in my admin. I have updated my question above. Thanks

Comment: Try: `docker-compose build --no-cache`

Comment: Were you able to get the image to build?

Comment: Yes, able to get it up. It was the version of some dependencies that created those error. Any tips to avoid this in the future?

Answer (score 0):

The issue indicates that you didn't install `node_modules` inside the `Dockerfile` using `npm install` or you overwrote those from the host using `COPY . /src` kind of statement.

Since the module you are using is a native module it needs to be compiled inside the docker image and not just copied from some place else as the same will not be compatible until unless the Host OS version and Image OS version are the same

Comment: Thanks. however, i have faced with a new error with code 0 once i enable the volume on admin app on docker-compose.yml. May i know what is the issue?

Comment: You cannot share the `node_volumes` using volumes, that will create the same problem

Comment: it is working on my primary app, however the admin app returns error code 0 with the same configuration in the same yml file. I am editing the question with dockerfile and .yml file later so that you can have a clearer picture

Comment: Can you delete all the `node_modules` on the host and then try to do `docker-compose up` and see what happens?

Comment: anyway i can check or trace the log etc for the error?

Comment: have a more detailed error. Have updated the question

Comment: notice i only able to get admin app working after unmounting volume  ./admin:/var/www/admin and /var/www/admin/node_modules running node admin_app.js on docker-compose.yml instead of dockerfile. However, with olume unmounted, any changes in admin folder is not reflected on the local site when running

Comment: @davidlee, can you define an environment variable `NODE_DEBUG=*` in your `admin` container and see if it shows in logs whats happening